# nginx-ingress version for a specific kubernetes version

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Would like to know how to check which nginx-ingress version is compatible with a specific kubernetes version? I visited https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx but each version just shows the enhancements/bug fixes. How to determine? I'm trying to upgrade a k8s 1.24 to 1.25, and the current version is 1.8.2.

Comment: did u check this link: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx#supported-versions-table

Comment: @holytrihead : I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further.

Answer (score 0):

**To update ingress nginx versions** : As Omer Sezer suggested, you need to check this [GIT LINK](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx#supported-versions-table) for the supported versions of ingress-nginx project. Ingress-Nginx versions may work on older versions, but the project does not make that guarantee. You need to compare which version of K8s you are using and update the Ingress Nginx version accordingly by following this doc for [Steps to Upgrade Ingress Nginx Version](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/upgrade/).

***For example*** : If you are using k8s supported version with 1.28, 1.27, 1.26, 1.25 then you need to use  v1.9.4 Ingress-NGINX version. It is a good practice to maintain the latest version.

**To update K8’s Versions** : If your K8s version is not the latest one then you plan to upgrade from 1.18.x to 1.24.x directly then the kubeadm upgrade plan command would fail. So to overcome that you would first have to upgrade from 1.18.x to 1.19.x and subsequently from 1.19.x to 1.20.x.

Post this, it is required to upgrade the Kubernetes cluster from [version 1.19.x to version 1.20.x to 1.21 to 1.22 to 1.23](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade/). You can Refer to these steps for [upgrading the kubernetes version](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/kubernetes-upgrade-version/).